# My components aren't showing up on my react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm a React beginner trying to make a simple frontend for a project which includes a search bar and a header at the moment. However, I can't get any of my components to display.

Here's my App.js file:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Container, InputGroup, FormControl, Button, Row, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <InputGroup className="mb-3" size="lg">
          <FormControl
          placeholder="Search For Artist"
          type="input"
          onKeyPress={event => {
            if (event.key == "Enter") {
              console.log("Pressed enter");
            }
          }}
          onChange={event => setSearchInput(event.target.value)}
          />

          <Button onClick={() => {console.log("Clicked Button")}}>
            Search
          </Button>
        </InputGroup>
      </Container>
      <Container>
        <Card>
          <Card.Img src='#' />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>Album Name Here</Card.Title>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you actually rendering the App component to the DOM anywhere?

Comment: Hi. What debugging have you done? Have you open the browser devtools to see if there are any errors in the console?

Comment: @JaredSmith My index.js file looks like this, and I think I'm rendering the component here:
'''
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
'''

Comment: @Andy I've opened up the console and it seems like there's a problem with my index.js file, and here's the error:
index.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function
    at ./src/index.js (index.js:7:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1
./src/index.js @ index.js:7
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `react-bootstrap` library. Please install using `npm install react-bootstrap`. Then run the application again.

[The working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-flower-edh6wg)